# Валидация строки из 3 или 6 символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

**Доброго времени суток.**

**Задача** сделать так, что бы #111 и #111111 проходили валидацию, а промежуточные значения типа #1111 # #11111 нет. Проблема заключается в том, что если написать `^#[[:xdigit:]]{3,6}$` то 4 и 5 чисел попадают, а как сделать так что либо три, либо 6 непонятно.

**Вариант который я нашел**, но он мне не нравится по причине что это костыль: `^#([[:xdigit:]]{3}){1,2}$`

**Хочу** найти аналог как если бы мы писали (один варинт|второй варинт) где "|" означает или. только не или это словосочетание или то, а или такое количчество символов, или другое.

**Спасибо!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Квантификатора `{x|y}` не существует.

У вас на выбор два варианта:

```
.{x}(.{y-x})?
.{x}(?:.{y-x})?
```

или

```
.{x}|.{y}
(.{x}|.{y})
(?:.{x}|.{y})
```

В вашем случае `^#([[:xdigit:]]{3}){1,2}$` не костыль, а лучшее решение, так как это выражение [находит](https://regex101.com/r/RvcwHO/2) строку, начинающуюся со знака `#`, за которым следует один или два повтора трёх символов шестнадцатеричных чисел и конец строки.

Другие варианты не лучше:

```
^#[[:xdigit:]]{3}([[:xdigit:]]{3})?$
^#([[:xdigit:]]{3}|[[:xdigit:]]{6})$
```